# Validating various radio buttons with jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, radio-button

I have 3 different radio button group in jQuery like so:

```
<tr class="toValidate">
    <td>Please rate question 1</td>
    <td>Yes<input type="radio" name="question1" value="yes" /></td>
    <td>No<input type="radio" name="question1" value="no" /></td>
    <td style='display:none'>ERROR GOES HERE</td>
</tr>
<tr class="toValidate" >
    <td>Please rate question 2</td>
    <td>Yes<input type="radio" name="question2" value="yes" /></td>
    <td>No<input type="radio" name="question2" value="no" /></td>
    <td style='display:none'>ERROR GOES HERE</td>
</tr>
```

I need that when the user submits the form, it loops through the radio button groups and for every group which doesn't have an option selected, the last td stating the error message is displayed. If both are not selected, both error messages are displayed not just the first one.

Any help?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($('input[name=question1]:checked').length == 0) {
    // Display an error for question1
}
if ($('input[name=question2]:checked').length == 0) {
    // Display an error for question2
}
```

If you have a large number of buttons to validate, you might do something like:

```
var questions = ['question1', 'question2'];
for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    if ($('input[name=' + questions[i] + ']:checked').length == 0) {
        // Display an error for questions[i]
    }
}
```

As an aside, *****PLEASE***** use the `<label>` tag to properly identify the label for your radio button. Users should be able to click "Yes" and not just the little circle of the radio button itself.

Either:

```
<td><label for="question1-yes">Yes</label><input type="radio" name="question1" value="yes" id="question1-yes" /></td>
```

Or:

```
<td><label>Yes<input type="radio" name="question1" value="yes" /></label></td>
```

Comment: +1 for using `label` properly. Though I'd **also** argue that the `form` should be laid-out using `fieldset`s and, possibly, a list, rather than a `table`.

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly modified your markup to include `class="error"`

```
<tr class="toValidate">
<td>Please rate question 1</td>
<td>Yes<input type="radio" name="question1" value="yes" /></td>
<td>No<input type="radio" name="question1" value="no" /></td>
<td class="error" style='display:none'>ERROR GOES HERE</td>
</tr>
<tr class="toValidate" >
<td>Please rate question 2</td>
<td>Yes<input type="radio" name="question2" value="yes" /></td>
<td>No<input type="radio" name="question2" value="no" /></td>
<td class="error" style='display:none'>ERROR GOES HERE</td>
</tr>
```

The below snippet should do what you need.

```
$('tr').each(function(){
    var currValue = $(':radio:checked', this).val(); 
    if (currValue!= "yes" || currValue != "no"){
        $(this).find('.error').show();
    }
});
```